# Instantiating a class in call method of T Callable Class

Tags: java, regex, multithreading, threadpool

Basically I've got a little threading class used by ExecutorService and a fixed thread pool. Each thread instantiates my threading class and the call method is fired, works great!

However I really need to call another class (via instantiation or static means) to process & return some data within the call method, however when trying this I understandably get concurrent.ExecutionException, along with related methods.

I think it will be easier to paste all my code here, note its very rough

MainController

```
package com.multithreading.excutorservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class MainController {


    private static List<String> urls;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        populateList();
        // futures to retrieve task results
        List<Future<ArrayList>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<ArrayList>>();
        // results
        List<ArrayList> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
        // pool with 5 threads
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); 

        // enqueue tasks
        for(String url: urls) {
            futures.add(exec.submit(new ThreadTask(url)));
        }

        // attempt to move ArrayLists within Future<ArrayList> into a normal ArrayList
        for(Future<ArrayList> future: futures) {
            try {
                results.add(future.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    //  for(ArrayList<String> s: results) {
    //      System.out.println(s);
    //  }
    }

    private static void populateList() {
        urls = new ArrayList<String>();

        urls.add("http://www.google.com");
        urls.add("http://www.msn.co.uk");
        urls.add("http://www.yahoo.co.uk");
        urls.add("http://www.google.com");
        urls.add("http://www.msn.co.uk");
        urls.add("http://www.yahoo.co.uk");
    }

}
```

ThreadTask

```
package com.multithreading.excutorservice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;



public class ThreadTask implements Callable<ArrayList> {
        private String url;
        HtmlParser parseHtml;

        public ThreadTask(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public ArrayList call() {

            int counter = 0;
            String html = null;

            try {
                URL myUrl = new URL(url);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myUrl.openStream()));

                while ((html = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //counter += inputLine.length();
                    html += html;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }

                ArrayList<String> storeLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
                HtmlParser par = new HtmlParser();
                storeLinks = par.returnNewUrls(html);

              //  for(String s: parseHtml) {
              //    System.out.println(s);
              //  }

                //returns an ArrayList of URLS which is stored in a List<Future<ArrayList>> temporarily
              return storeLinks;

        }
   }
```

HtmlParser

```
package com.multithreading.excutorservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HtmlParser {

    private final String regex_links = "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))"; 
    private ArrayList<String> extractedUrls;

    public ArrayList<String> returnNewUrls (String data) {

        extractedUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex_links);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
        System.out.println("Test");

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Test");
            extractedUrls.add(m.group(1));

        }

        return getLinks();
    }

   //returns the links
    public ArrayList getLinks() {
        return extractedUrls;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the full stack trace of the exception is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some pretty weird stuff here. Multiple threads are accessing the same static extractedUrls field, and each call to returnNewUrls creates a new field. In your returnNewUrls  method, create a new ArrayList which is *local to the method scope*. Something along the lines of:

```
public static ArrayList<String> returnNewUrls(String data) {
  ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
  addStuffToUrlsList();
  return urls;
}
```

Another thing - not a bug, but you're doing unnecessary stuff - in the call method you don't need to create a new list if you're just assigning to a variable:

```
ArrayList<String> parseHtml = new ArrayList<String>();
parseHtml = HtmlParser.returnNewUrls(html);
```

This is better:

```
ArrayList<String> parseHtml = HtmlParser.returnNewUrls(html);
```

Comment: wow forgotten I'd tried static out, ended leaving a load of incorrect code, thanks

Comment: As @rfq pointed out, static fields should be avoided, especially when working with threads!

Comment: The problem ended up being something to do with parsing, but nevertheless you helped, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several concurrent tasks, but they use the same variable HtmlParser.extractedUrls? without any synchronization. Move this variable inside the returnNewUrls  method.
BTW even without concurrency, using static variables is not encouraged, especially in a case like that, where it can easily be replaced with a local variable.